# Loathing IE and it's refusal to respond to JQuery Post

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

Ladies / Gents:

Doing a $.post which works fine in Chrome & FireFox. IE - not so much...the success callback (addTicketAndRender()) never gets hit:

http://jsfiddle.net/AeQxJ/1/

I've read something about needing to do "cache-busting" against IE with my POST, but I'm relatively new to this stuff so don't know if that's the appropriate thing to try and if so, how to do it.

Source:

```
function addTicketAndRender(incomingTicket) {

    console.log("Add and Render");
    alert(incomingTicket);
}



$(document).ready(function() {

    console.log('ready');

    // variables to feed trusted ticket retrieval
    var trustedURL = "http://tableau.russellchristopher.org/trusted",
        userName = "foo",
        serverURL = "http://tableau.russellchristopher.org/";



    $.post(trustedURL, {
        username: userName,
        server: serverURL,
        client_ip: "",
        target_site: "",
        cache: "false"
    }, function(response) {
        addTicketAndRender(response);
    });

});​
```

Little help, please?

**Update1:** Switched this out to an ajax post: No difference. Still good on Chrome and Firefox, still dead in IE:

```
    $.ajax( {
      url : trustedURL,
      type: "POST",
      data : {
        username : userName,
        server : serverURL,
        client_ip : "",
        target_site : "" 
      },    
      cache : false


    } ).done( addTicketAndRender );
```

**Update2:** Integrated additional cache-busting technique. Same behavior - Chrome/FF works, nothing from IE - Using Fiddler, I can see the POST go out when running the code below from http://jsfiddle.net/AeQxJ/3//. In IE, that never happens. Tested outside of jsfiddle and see the same result.  Next step: Rule out stupid IE browser settings on my part by testing on a box where I haven't touched browser settings.

```
function addTicketAndRender(incomingTicket){


    alert(incomingTicket);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   // variables to feed trusted ticket retrieval

    var trustedURL = "http://tableau.russellchristopher.org/trusted",
        userName = "foo",
        serverURL = "http://tableau.russellchristopher.org/";

var number=Math.floor(Math.random()*1);
$.ajax( {
      url : trustedURL + "?" + number,
      type: "POST",
      data : {
        username : userName,
        server : serverURL,
        client_ip : "",
        target_site : "" 
      },    
      cache : false
     } ).done( addTicketAndRender );

});​
```

**Update 4:** Ruled out my copy of IE as an issue. Added error trapping code to the POST, and ONLY when running in IE, I see this thrown:

```
         error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
              alert(xhr.statusText);
              alert(textStatus);
              alert(error);

//output:

//    xhr.StatusText: No Transport
//    testSttus: Error
//    error: No Transport
```

Searching on "IE No Transport jquery POST" leads me here:

[jQuery Call to WebService returns "No Transport" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241088/jquery-call-to-webservice-returns-no-transport-error)

Post indicates adding `jQuery.support.cors = true;` should resolve the issue, but when I do, errors are returned:

```
//output:

//    xhr.StatusText: Error: Access is denied
//    testSttus: Error
//    error: Error: Access is denied
```

Comment: Did you try checking the error() value to see what is being thrown?

Comment: Did you try using the jQuery.ajax function with the error method to see what the error message is?  You might need to be using [jsonp](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/) due to a violation of the same origin policy.

Comment: Wait, why do that work in chrome and firefox at all? What happened to the same origin policy?

Comment: Oh, and by the way, it works in IE10...

Comment: i would suggest adding an error handler to your $.ajax attempt and see what the exception coming back is.

Comment: @MarkM Thanks, I already have Access-Control-Allow-Origin in my headers to avoid this.

Comment: @Alxandr I actually have Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers in my httpd to allow calls from a couple domains.

Comment: @jbabey Can I just do something like .error(function())? Never tried this.

Comment: @RussellChristopher yes, check out [5 ways to make ajax calls with jquery](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/), you add the `error` function just like you had a `success` function before.

Comment: Is IE blocking your script? Have you tried adding `<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->` to your doc? [see this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038724/how-to-automaticaly-allow-blocked-content-in-ie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cache: false is not working for you, the old school way was to add a get parameter to the url, like a random number, so:

```
var number=Math.floor(Math.random()*1)
$.ajax( {
      url : trustedURL + "?" + number,
      type: "POST",
      data : {
        username : userName,
        server : serverURL,
        client_ip : "",
        target_site : "" 
      },    
      cache : false


    } ).done( addTicketAndRender );
```

This should help you debugging as well (change from random number to sequential). If still doesnt work I remove `.done` and use something like `complete` i.e.

```
$.ajax( {
      url : trustedURL,
      type: "POST",
      data : {
        username : userName,
        server : serverURL,
        client_ip : "",
        target_site : "" 
      },    
      cache : false,
      complete : function() {
         addTicketAndRender
      }
  });
```

One last thing, if your doing this using your jsfiddle page, make sure you remove console.log() from your code, as this will cause IE to break (it doesn't understand console.log).

Comment: Madness. Added your suggestion to http://jsfiddle.net/AeQxJ/3/. It works in Chrome/Firefox - I see the POST request going out. In IE9, nothing. @Alxandr says it works in IE10 for him, however.

Comment: This brings up an alert box for me : http://jsfiddle.net/P4Xvu/ , so it is completing the ajax action. Note I also removed the .done and replaced with complete

Comment: You're right. It returns the same statusText of "No Transport" as my error handler. I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087549/access-denied-to-jquery-script-on-ie which seems to be the solution. IE doesn't actually support Cross Domain requests with jquery, even if the SERVER does http://martinkool.com/post/18182537575/jquery-support-for-cross-domain-xhr-in-ie So, I have to use this XDR thing, or wait till IE 10, which will support what I need.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
$.post( ...
    cache: "false"
    ...
```

To:

```
$.ajax(...
    cache: false,
    ...
```

Note, The first cache is a meaningless string, while the later is a Boolean false.

Comment: Makes sense - Did, and no joy: http://jsfiddle.net/AeQxJ/2/. The cache-busting I read about had something to with literally appending a unique value to the POST - like a timestamp or something. Does that ring a bell for you and/or sound reasonable?

Comment: @RussellChristopher. Yes, this is how it works. anyway, do you see errors in the console? in firebug?

Comment: Again, new to this stuff - I can use Firebug to monitor work I'm doing in IE? It also looks like I need to do more quick on the $.ajax call - not as simple as swapping out post/ajax...wait 5 :)

Comment: @RussellChristopher. I can't debug for you... You should [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022089/how-can-i-watch-i-e-debug-xmlhttprequest-actions-in-ie8-using-firebug-li) and learn how to do it yourself. tell my what the results are.

Comment: IE8+ has a built in debugger, use it and use Fiddler to watch http traffic.

Comment: @epascarello. Read the comment before you... :) 15sec.

Comment: Fixed up the $.ajax request, put a breakpoint on it, and stepped through. Also have fiddler on to see if the POST is actually made. I hit $.ajax and jump into jquery1.7.2.min.js at which point I honestly lose track of what's going on. I step over until I'm back out into my code. Success callback is not hit. Interesting thing is that I NEVER see a POST in Fiddler.

Comment: @gdoron That's what I thought, but the same ajax function is working fine in Chrome & FireFox http://jsfiddle.net/AeQxJ/3 In Chrome/FF, I see the post going out even when I'm running from inside jsfiddle. Same thing from IE never POSTS. I'm beginning to wonder if I've just done something goofy to my browser settings. May try this on a virgin IE install on a different machine...

Answer (score 0):

`$.post` is only a shorthand version of `$.ajax()` link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

If you need more control I suggest using `$.ajax()` since you have a lot more option with the "native" method. Link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Besides a good coding tips concerning jQuery.ajax() is always set `$.ajax({cache: false})` somewhere as a default, since IE is (surprise) the only browser with `cache: true` as default

Answer (score 0):

IE tends to trip on `console.log('');` statements. Try to wrap it into a Log() function:

```
function Log(text) {
    try {
        console.log(text);
    }
    catch (e) {
    }
}
```

If that fixes your problem, you'll want to use [this approach to using console.log()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3767958/299756) throughout your project.

Comment: Thanks, I removed those for IE testing.